# WooCommerce: Disabling checkout fields with a filter hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, checkout

I have try to disable the "required" property of several checkout fields at the same time using `woocommerce_checkout_fields` filter hook, with no success.

Plugins are not working properly either. This is my code:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;

$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = false;

     return $fields;
}
```

What is wrong? 
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the `unset()` function for this purpose and you can do-it this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
    return $fields;
}
```

*You will need to paste this code in function.php file located in your active child theme or theme.*

---

*You have changed your question with **an update***: Here it is my new answer

**Making the address fields optional** (regarding your update):

You have to use a different filter hook for that purpose. There are 2 different filter hooks:

**1) For Billing Fields:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_optional_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function wc_optional_billing_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_city']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['billing_phone']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

**2) For shipping fields:**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'wc_optional_shipping_fields', 10, 1 );
function wc_optional_shipping_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['shipping_phone']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

---

**To make the address fields required:**

You can use the same hooks and functions above, changing for each field `false` to `true`.

---

*You will need to paste this code in function.php file located in your active child theme or theme.*

Reference: [Customizing checkout fields using hooks](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2)

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I need to make several fields "not required", not fully disabling them. That actually works fine.