# Make woocommerce checkout fields optional

Tags: woocommerce, field, option-type, checkout

I have already followed the method to make the checkout fields optional with the codes below. However, I found that the alert to fill in address field jumped out when the non-login user submit the order.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields($address_fields) {

    $address_fields['first_name']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['last_name']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = '';
    $address_fields['address_2']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = '';
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['city']['required'] = false;

return $address_fields;
}
```

By the way, I also tried to make the billing and shipping fields optional separately as the method in the link [WooCommerce: Disabling checkout fields with a filter hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37791580/woocommerce-disabling-checkout-fields-with-a-filter-hook).

Comment: Your code just works perfectly for logged or non logged in users…

Comment: I think so. But the alert to fill in address field for non logged in users and  the alert to fill in postcode for logged in users.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on which checkout fields you would like to make optional (or required), there are two filters that you will need to hook into. The first filter is [`woocommerce_default_address_fields`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_default_address_fields/) and is for the address fields, the second is [`woocommerce_billing_fields`](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_billing_fields/) and is for the `billing_phone` and `billing_email` fields.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'adjust_requirement_of_checkout_address_fields' );
function adjust_requirement_of_checkout_address_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['first_name']['required']   = false;
    $fields['last_name']['required']    = false;
    $fields['company']['required']      = false;
    $fields['country']['required']      = false;
    $fields['address_1']['required']    = false;
    $fields['address_2']['required']    = false;
    $fields['city']['required']         = false;
    $fields['state']['required']        = false;
    $fields['postcode']['required']     = false;

    return $fields;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'adjust_requirement_of_checkout_contact_fields');
function adjust_requirement_of_checkout_contact_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_phone']['required']    = false;
    $fields['billing_email']['required']    = false;

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Should be accepted answer, works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

go to this thread [Make checkout fields required in Woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310107/make-checkout-fields-required-in-woocommerce-checkout) and change true to false for the fields you don't need to be required
ex : change $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = true;
to $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = false;