# Make checkout fields required in Woocommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, checkout

For some reason, all the fields in Billing Address are marked as optional - customers are leaving the billing address fields blank and then their payments are being rejected (by Square, who is our payment processor).

I cannot find anywhere to make these fields required, and cannot figure out why they would be marked as optional in any case.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

UPDATE

I've even tried the following:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'force_billing_fields', 1000, 1);
function force_billing_fields($fields) {
  $fields['billing_first_name']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_last_name']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_city']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_country']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_email']['required'] = true;
  $fields['billing_phone']['required'] = true;

  return $fields;
}
```

And they're still marked as optional, except the billing phone and country are now marked as required. But the rest are still optional.

Comment: There is something that is making those fields optional as by default they are required. So you need to find the guilty that can be a customization, something in your theme or a plugin. You can also look to [**Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) or searching in [**this related related threads**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwoocommerce%5D+checkout+required)

Comment: Obviously... I've searched all my custom code, and I'm not modifying those fields anywhere. I'll look through the plugins and see what's going on.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec please see update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you can do if you don't find the guilty as explained on my comment is to use the following *(using here a highest hook priority if some other code is already using those hooks)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields', 'customising_checkout_fields', 1000, 1 );
function customising_checkout_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['first_name']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['last_name']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['company']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['country']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['city']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['state']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['postcode']['required'] = true;

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

For billing phone and email you can try

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_billing_fields', 1000, 1);
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_email']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing_phone']['required'] = true;

    return $fields;
}
```

or

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_billing_fields', 1000, 1);
function custom_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email']['required'] = true;
    $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['required'] = true;

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: I have added some other hooks for billing  email and phone…

Comment: Also, I searched in all the plugins for `add_filter('woocommerce' and no plugin is hooking onto any of those fields filters... this is very weird

Comment: Why we put 1000? I am trying the solution but it is not working :(

Comment: @MariaGeorgali 1000 is the hook priority, that allows to make this code running after other plugins that may use the same hook.

Comment: I have tried to make it priority 100000000 and still nothing, tried different filters, it's ignoring me more than girls on dating site.