# Woocommerce checkout remove-delete unknown required checkbox field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

I'm using the latest woocommerce and flatsome theme. There is a visible-required field during guest checkout so i can't find a way to delete-disable this even with Checkout Field Editor (Checkout Manager) plugin.

As a temporary workaround, i've tried to completely hide the additional information fields group from checkout. This field went hidden (and the additional information textarea field as well) but it was still part of the validation.

Thanks for the support!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make checkout fields required in Woocommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51310107/make-checkout-fields-required-in-woocommerce-checkout)